# What time zone do I initialize QDateTime in?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I need my Qt application to run a task on all international computers at the same instant regardless of time zone. The application downloads the required date + time from the web in UTC. What time zone must I initialize QDateTime with? UTC? Or does it depend on the local time zone?

For example:

Say the required date + time is: 4/22/2013 at 14:00 UTC

How would I initialize this for a computer that is configured with EST and another computer that is configured with PST?

Would doing:

```
QDateTime test(QDate(2013, 22, 4), QTime(14, 0, 0));
```

mean that all international computers will run the task at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [QDateTime constructor](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qdatetime.html#QDateTime-3) you are using takes a `Qt::TimeSpec` parameter, you can choose `Qt::UTC` instead of the default which is to use the local time. Then all the computers would run at the same time.

But if you're downloading the time from a service, it's presumably being transferred in ISO-8601 format. Then it's probably much easier to do it like this:

```
QDateTime test = QDateTime::fromString(dateAsAString, Qt::ISODate);
```

If the time service isn't returning the time in ISO-8601, then it is a bug in the service.